# cross platform reference to specific drive/directory

Tags: file, operating-system, cross-platform, drive

Is there a way to express a specific drive in both windows/linux?  Windows usually uses"D:\etc" and Ubuntu/etc uses something like "/media/user/drive_name".  Is there a awy to just refer to something like "/dev/sdc1" which both Windows and Ubuntu will recognize as the same drive?

I am trying to put this in a config file for a python program which can be run on an external data drive from an internal drive containing multiple OSs.  The program has to refer to a separate external data drive, but I would like the program to work the same way for all of the OSs.

Is this possible?

Comment: can't you just modify the config file for each host or do a system test in the code?

Comment: I may look into that, but I was hoping that all of the program codes and references could be contained in the external drive which it was running from.  If you change where the config file is based on the OS, you're still going to have to modify the source code in a case by case basis.  I didn't create this source code for the program, so I'm not incredible comfortable changing things around, but I may give it a shot if I can find the right places.

Answer (score 1):

Either you just need to account for your OS type in each machines properties file or test for the OS in the code and act accordingly.

```
import os
if os.name == "windows"
    path = "D:/windows/path"
elif
    path = "/unix/path"
```